# Given an AST, is there a working library for getting the source?

Tags: python, abstract-syntax-tree

Is there a way to convert a given Python abstract syntax tree (AST) to a source code?

[Here](http://www.dalkescientific.com/writings/diary/archive/2010/02/22/instrumenting_the_ast.html) is a good example of how to use Python's `ast` module, specifically a `NodeTransformer`. I was looking for a way to convert the resulting AST back to source, so the changes can be inspected visually.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

The Python source tree contains an implementation of this: [unparse.py](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/3.8/Tools/parser/unparse.py) in the Demo/parser directory

**Editor's note**: With the introduction of [`ast.unparse()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/ast.html#ast.unparse) in Python 3.9, [unparse.py has been removed](https://github.com/python/cpython/commit/27fc3b6f3fc49a36d3f962caac5c5495696d12ed#diff-0821b37fe28e7a1acf377e02c8927fd16125a7274d3f427e4efdd63cd3e06740), so the above link has been updated to point to 3.8.

Comment: Thanks. It looks somewhat buggy, but I can use it as a starting point.

Comment: Interesting, I didn't look closely, what sorts of bugs do you see?

Comment: Scratch that. Looks like it is alright in Python 2.7. I was trying on 2.6 and I found problems with things like `for ... else`, but 2.7 is fine so far.

Comment: Who wrote this? Only reference I could find is from this [README](http://svn.python.org/projects/python/trunk/Demo/README) "They were all written by me[...]" with no name.

Comment: is there something similar to 'ast.unparse()' for Python3.7 ?

Answer (score 7):

As of Python 3.9, the ast module provides an [unparse](https://docs.python.org/3.9/library/ast.html#ast.unparse) function for this:

> Unparse an ast.AST object and generate a string with code that would produce an equivalent ast.AST object if parsed back with ast.parse()

Comment: Thanks. Yes, I am keeping an eye on it. Seems to be the best solution.

Answer (score 5):

A nice third-party library I found: [`astunparse`](https://astunparse.readthedocs.io/en/latest/) which is based on the `unparse.py` suggested by Ned in [his answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3794251/2650249). Example:

```
import ast
import astunparse

code = '''
class C:
    def f(self, arg):
        return f'{arg}'

print(C().f("foo" + 'bar'))
'''

print(astunparse.unparse(ast.parse(code)))
```

running which yields

```
class C():

    def f(self, arg):
        return f'{arg}'
print(C().f(('foo' + 'bar')))
```

Another neat function is `astunparse.dump` which pretty-prints the code object:

```
astunparse.dump(ast.parse(code))
```

Output:

```
Module(body=[
  ClassDef(
    name='C',
    bases=[],
    keywords=[],
    body=[FunctionDef(
      name='f',
      args=arguments(
        args=[
          arg(
            arg='self',
            annotation=None),
          arg(
            arg='arg',
            annotation=None)],
        vararg=None,
        kwonlyargs=[],
        kw_defaults=[],
        kwarg=None,
        defaults=[]),
      body=[Return(value=JoinedStr(values=[FormattedValue(
        value=Name(
          id='arg',
          ctx=Load()),
        conversion=-1,
        format_spec=None)]))],
      decorator_list=[],
      returns=None)],
    decorator_list=[]),
  Expr(value=Call(
    func=Name(
      id='print',
      ctx=Load()),
    args=[Call(
      func=Attribute(
        value=Call(
          func=Name(
            id='C',
            ctx=Load()),
          args=[],
          keywords=[]),
        attr='f',
        ctx=Load()),
      args=[BinOp(
        left=Str(s='foo'),
        op=Add(),
        right=Str(s='bar'))],
      keywords=[])],
    keywords=[]))])
```

Answer (score 1):

Have a look at http://pypi.python.org/pypi/sourcecodegen/0.6.14

Comment: I know this is ancient, but this doesn't work with the `ast` module --- it only works with ASTs generated by the `compiler.ast` module.