# Complement function of compiler.parse() in python

Tags: python-2.7

The compiler.parse() function in python give me the compiled code of an expression.
For ex:
`compiler.parse('a/b/c')`

generates

`Module(None, Stmt([Discard(Div((Div((Name('a'), Name('b'))), Name('c'))))]))`

How can I do the reverse of it; meaning given the compiled statement how can I get `a/b/c`?

PS :: I know that compiler module is deprecated in python2.7 and python3.0 but it seems to be the only thing for my work!

Comment: possible duplicate of [Given an AST, is there a working library for getting the source?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3774162/given-an-ast-is-there-a-working-library-for-getting-the-source)

Answer (score 0):

[uncompyle](https://github.com/gstarnberger/uncompyle) actually uncompiles 2.7 bytecode, so you might want check if you can hook into that with your parsed code after compilation.