# Python ast (Abstract Syntax Trees): get back source string of subnode

Tags: python, parsing

I use

```
>>> import ast
>>> T = ast.parse('a * (b + c)', mode='eval').body
```

to get an abstract syntax tree of some (mathematically looking; but this shouldn't matter) expression.

Now I want to get back the source string of some particular node. For example

```
>>> get_source_back(T.right)
'(b + c)'
```

Is there a solution for this somewhere?

(Of course I could use .walk or NodeVisitor and manually specify how to construct a string out of a node. But this does not give me the original source and I have to be careful with parentheses and so on.)

Comment: getting the source back is not a simple task, this modified version of unparse.py  https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/master/Tools/parser/unparse.py would get the source back if using exec,http://pastebin.com/BUeGLdid

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Given an AST, is there a working library for getting the source?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3774162/given-an-ast-is-there-a-working-library-for-getting-the-source)

Answer (score 2):

You won't get the *exact* *original* source back.  But the [astor](https://github.com/berkerpeksag/astor/) package will give you back source that will *recompile* identically to the original source.

**Edited to add**  The reconstituted source provided by the version on github is substantially better than the source provided by the most recent release (e.g. fewer parentheses and better handling of docstrings).  A new release is imminent, I think.

(And the unparser package mentioned in the comments pessimistically puts parentheses on everything.)