# is there any way to revert back the AST tree from the dump file of the tree?

Tags: python, abstract-syntax-tree, dump

c is a parsed tree of a python code:

`c=ast.parse('''
for x in y:
    print(x)
''')`

d is the dump file of tree-c

```
d=ast.dump(c)
```

the content of d is the following string:

```
Module(
    body=[For(target=Name(id='x', ctx=Store()), iter=Name(id='y', ctx=Load()),
    body=[Expr(value=Call(func=Name(id='print', ctx=Load()), 
    args=[Name(id='x', ctx=Load())], keywords=[]))], orelse=[])])
```

I've looked around the net to see if I could find a method to use the content of d, to revert back to the tree c.

Any suggestions?

Thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `eval` to get the `ast` object from the string:

```
ast_obj = eval(d)
```

Then, there exist various third party libraries that can convert back to source ([Given an AST, is there a working library for getting the source?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3774162/given-an-ast-is-there-a-working-library-for-getting-the-source), [Python ast (Abstract Syntax Trees): get back source string of subnode](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32146363/python-ast-abstract-syntax-trees-get-back-source-string-of-subnode))

Comment: Thank you! That is exactly what I was looking for. It works perfectly

Comment: Are you sure this works? I get "NameError: name 'Module' is not defined" whenever I do: eval('Module(body=[For(target=Name(id='x', ctx=Store()), iter=Name(id='y', ctx=Load()),body=[Expr(value=Call(func=Name(id='print', ctx=Load()), args=[Name(id='x', ctx=Load())], keywords=[]))], orelse=[])])').

Comment: Hi @berniethejet, yes I am sure this works.  The error "NameError: name ... is not defined" usually indicates a missing import statement.  In your case, try adding `from ast import *` at the top.

Comment: Thanks for this @BenJones, if you hadn't told me I'd never had figured it out. But why doesn't 'import ast' work here? What does 'from ast import * ' bring in that 'import ast' misses? (Of course I had used 'import ast' when I first tried.)

Comment: There is a pretty big difference between 'import X' and 'from X import *': https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12270954/difference-between-import-x-and-from-x-import/12270980#12270980

Comment: Don't take this the wrong way, but I'm a little surprised you are playing with the AST without knowing import syntax/namespaces

Comment: Thanks @BenJones. No offense taken. I'm teaching Mathematica to write Python via the AST, and learning Python at the same time ;).