# Insert docstring attributes in a python file

Tags: python, string, insert

We are using napolean style docstring for python modules. But there is a need to auto populate additional attributes in the docstring called `Data Owner` and `DAL Owner` so that the given function looks like this:

```
def func(self, arg1=None, arg2=None):
"""
Returns the timeseries for the specified arg1 and arg2.
Args:
    arg1: argument 1
    arg2: argument 2
Returns:
    DataFrame containing timeseries of arg1 for arg2.

DAL Owner: Team IT
Data Owner: Team A
"""
```

These additional attributes and their values for a given function are provided in a separate csv file. The way I was thinking was to have a script (awk, sed?) that will

- extract all the function names in a given python file. Can easily do it in python
- for those function names, check if the owners exist in the csv file and if so create a mapping of the function name and owners. Doable

Now, this is the part which I havent figured out and dont know the best way forward. For a given function name and owners, I need to go back into the python file and add the owners to the docstring if it exists. I am thinking some sort of awk script but not quite sure

- Find the function that matches the pattern
- For that pattern, see if doctsring exists, triple quotation marks after closing parenthesis
- If docstring exists, add additional two lines for the owners before the closing triple quotation
- If docstring does not exists, then insert the two lines for owners between tripe quotations on the line after function declaration.

I know this is a lot of steps but can anyone provide insight with the previous 4 bullet points to insert the additional attributes to docstring given the function, attributes and the python file. Will a linux utility like sed, awk be more useful or should I go the python route. Is there some other option that's easier to implement.

Comment: You could use the ast package to parse the source, insert/amend docstrings and rewrite the code.  However this approach could cause large diffs in your version control system, unless you auto-format your code.

Comment: I am ok with diffs in version control as long as the code remains the same incuding comments. From what I have read online ast ignores comments. Moreover while I have been able to visit the nodes and get the docstring, I still havent been able to assign that docstring back to the function. Could you please tell me how I can assign a docstring to a function in AST

Comment: https://www.sphinx-doc.org/en/master/ looks like a better alternative

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The process for assigning a new docstring in an ast is:

1. Get the existing docstring using [`ast.get_docstring`](https://docs.python.org/3.6/library/ast.html#ast.get_docstring)
2. Create a new ast node with amended content
3. If the existing dostring is `None`, insert the new node at the start of the parent node's body
4. If there was an existing docstring, replace it's node with the new node
5. Use the [unparse](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/3.7/Tools/parser/unparse.py)<sup>*</sup> tool from Cpython Tools to generate the new source (you may need to download this from github - ensure you get the version that matches your python version)

Here's some example code:

```
$  cat fixdocstrings.py                            
import ast                                                                               
import io
from unparse import Unparser


class DocstringWriter(ast.NodeTransformer):
    def visit_FunctionDef(self, node):
        docstring = ast.get_docstring(node)
        new_docstring_node = make_docstring_node(docstring)
        if docstring:
            # Assumes the existing docstring is the first node 
            # in the function body.
            node.body[0] = new_docstring_node
        else:
            node.body.insert(0, new_docstring_node)
        return node


def make_docstring_node(docstring):
    if docstring is None:
        content = "A new docstring"
    else:
        content = docstring + " -- amended"
    s = ast.Str(content)
    return ast.Expr(value=s)


if __name__ == "__main__":
    tree = ast.parse(open("docstringtest.py").read())
    transformer = DocstringWriter()
    new_tree = transformer.visit(tree)
    ast.fix_missing_locations(new_tree)
    buf = io.StringIO()
    Unparser(new_tree, buf)
    buf.seek(0)
    print(buf.read())

$  cat docstringtest.py 
def foo():
    pass


def bar():
    """A docstring."""

$  python fixdocstrings.py 


def foo():
    'A new docstring'
    pass

def bar():
    'A docstring. -- amended'
```

(I answered something similar for myself for python2.7, [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/46388956/5320906))

<sup>*</sup> As of Python 3.9, the ast module provides an [unparse](https://docs.python.org/3.9/library/ast.html#ast.unparse) function that can be used instead of the `unparse` tool: `src = ast.unparse(new_tree)`

Comment: thank you. just one question -- is it always guaranteed that docstring is the first node in the function body.

Comment: @Fizi a docstring is defined as the first expression in a class module or function, so yes.  ast.get_docstring looks for the first node and if a "docstring" appears later in an object's code it won't be assigned to `__doc__`.

Comment: I have run int another major problem, which is that the comments aren't preserved.. Anyway to do that?

Comment: I had to move away from AST and use regex instead

Comment: There's no way to preserve comments using the core ast module, but something like [red baron](https://pypi.org/project/redbaron/) might work (I've never used it).  Alternatively you could either used sed to wrap your comments in quotes then unwrap after docstring processing, or [delete the comment parts from the diff after processing](https://kennyballou.com/blog/2015/10/art-manually-edit-hunks/).  Though I've not tried either of these approaches.

Comment: Yeah I made a home brewed solution using regex substitution. It seems to do the job. Thanks for all your help.