# How to modify python function docstring and write to python file

Tags: python, python-3.x

I need to use a python script to modify the docstring of a function in another python script, and save it to a file overwriting

```
├── test.py
├── modify.py
```

```
# test.py 'Function file of docstring to be modified'
def hello_world():
    """
    this function is a demo
    mulit lines"""
    return 'hello world'

    """
    # This is an interference note and cannot be modified here
    mulit lines"""
```

```
# modify.py 'Modify the docstring function of test.py'

from test import hello_world

def modify_docstring():

    print(hello_world.__doc__) # this function is a demo
    hello_world.__doc__ = 'I\' am new docstring' 

    print(hello_world.__doc__) # I' am new docstring  # I can assign values in this way, but only in memory. How to modify and write the test.py file?
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Insert docstring attributes in a python file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53564301/insert-docstring-attributes-in-a-python-file)

Comment: @GinoMempin It's a bit useful, but there are also problems. The triple quotes in the docstring that comes after parsing become single quotes, while the multi-line docstrings are directly connected into one line with the \n symbol. This is fatal. I don't know if there is any way to deal with it.